# Is birational equivalence between Elliptic Curves a transitive property?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, birational-geometry

Say I have three elliptic curves, E1, E2, and E3. If I can find maps that make E1 and E2 birationally equivalent and E2 and E3 birationally equivalent, does this imply that a map making E1 and E3 birationally equivalent must exist?

Comment: Yes, this should hold. A birational equivalence is an isomorphism of (Zariski-)open subschemes, and as any two open (Zariski-)open subsets have nonempty intersection, one can see that this is transitive by choosing the resepective open subsets small enough.

Comment: Two birationally equivalent elliptic curves should actually be isomorphic, since birational equivalence is determined by the field of rational functions, but the field of rational functions on a curve determines the isomorphism type of this curve?

Comment: It means almost the same https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43013/what-does-birational-equivalence-mean-in-a-cryptographic-context